# How can I rewrite this MySQL query for returning a count?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have this query:

```
SELECT accounts.id
FROM accounts
  LEFT JOIN account_properties ON account_properties.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY accounts.id
HAVING COUNT(account_properties.id) = 0
```

It returns a list of all account IDs whose account does not have any account properties. How can I get the count of all accounts without properties?

```
SELECT COUNT(accounts.id)
FROM accounts
  LEFT JOIN account_properties ON account_properties.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY accounts.id
HAVING COUNT(account_properties.id) = 0
```

This does not work and only returns a list of 1s.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably find these queries faster... assuming that id is a unique identifier of an account.

For the ids:

```
   SELECT accounts.id
     FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN account_properties ON account_properties.account_id = accounts.id
    WHERE account_properties.id IS NULL
```

For the count of ids:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN account_properties ON account_properties.account_id = accounts.id
    WHERE account_properties.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Using GROUP BY / HAVING for retrieving the IDs felt wrong in first place. This is much better. Didn't know about the IS NULL trick for checking if any columns have been joined.

Comment: Yeah, tha'ts what I meant to say

Comment: @Aich My pleasure.. it's fairly common. Don't be afraid to wrap a query with a count if you have to though. If this is what you are going with.. kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select count(*) from (SELECT accounts.id
    FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN account_properties ON account_properties.account_id = accounts.id
    WHERE exists account_properties.id
    GROUP BY accounts.id)
```

Comment: I think the COUNT used for the HAVING will always be 1 (unless the account has more than 1 property).

Comment: Isn't that how he's filtering which records have prop of 0?  or are you saying even if it doesn't = 0 it will still come back as 1 ?

Comment: Yes, `COUNT` really just counts rows, with the `LEFT JOIN` every account will get at least one row. And his query is failing to return the results he expects because of that.

Comment: how that then?  I used where exists instead?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never actually used `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `ap`.account_id IS NULL AS noProperties
   , COUNT(DISTINCT `a`.id) AS accountCount
FROM `accounts` AS `a`
  LEFT JOIN `account_properties` AS `ap` N `ap`.account_id = `a`.id
GROUP BY noProperties
HAVING noProperties
;
```

The GROUP BY gets the number of accounts with and without properties, and the HAVING filters the results so that only the count for no property accounts is in the final result.